# How to set CellValueFactory to functions of various properties in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, model-view-controller, tableview

I was building a download manager in javafx in the MVC pattern and got into some trouble. I wanted to list the downloads in a TableView with all properties in various columns.

Suppose I have a model like this.

```
class Download{
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part1;
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part2;

    public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> getPart1Property(){
        return part1;
    }
    public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> getPart2Property(){
        return part2;
    }
}
```

Now I have javafx GUI set up with a table view like this.

```
TableView<Download> table=new TableView<Download>();
table.setItems(.. Observable list of Download objects ...);
```

If I wanted to add a column in the table-view for the value of part1, I could do it like this.

```
 TableColumn<Download,Integer> part1 = new TableColumn<Download,Integer>("Part 1 value");
 part1.setCellValueFactory(
            (TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Download, Integer> download) -> download.getValue().getPart1Property());
```

Now I need a column in the table view that shows the **sum of the values of part1 and part2**. **How can I achieve this in javafx?**

I have read the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) but sadly couldn't find any way I could accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please follow fx-naming conventions - in your data class that would be `part1Property()` (_not_: getPart1Property()). Also don't overspecify the type of return value, use StringProperty (_not_ SimpleStringProperty)

Comment: Thank you! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the sum of the required values in the cellValueFactory.

```
TableColumn<Download, Integer> totalCol = new TableColumn<>("Total");
        totalCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().getPart1() + param.getValue().getPart2()));
```

A complete working demo is below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomCellValueFactoryDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Download>  downloads = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        downloads.add(new Download(23,56));
        downloads.add(new Download(56,43));
        downloads.add(new Download(97,3));
        downloads.add(new Download(67,23));

        TableView<Download> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Download, Integer> part1Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 1");
        part1Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part1Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Integer> part2Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 2");
        part2Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part2Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Integer> totalCol = new TableColumn<>("Total");
        totalCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().getPart1() + param.getValue().getPart2()));


        tableView.getColumns().addAll(part1Col,part2Col, totalCol);
        tableView.setItems(downloads);

        Scene sc = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class Download{
        SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);
        SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part2= new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);
        public Download(int p1, int p2){
            part1.set(p1);
            part2.set(p2);

        }

        public int getPart1() {
            return part1.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part1Property() {
            return part1;
        }

        public void setPart1(int part1) {
            this.part1.set(part1);
        }

        public int getPart2() {
            return part2.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part2Property() {
            return part2;
        }

        public void setPart2(int part2) {
            this.part2.set(part2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem. If later on the value of part1 changes in the program, the value of part1 column changes correctly, but the value of the total column does not change. This is due to the fact that you are creating a new SimpleObjectProperty object with a constant value while setting the cellValueFactory. In my program the value of part1 changes constantly, so the above solution does not work Put `downloads.get(1).setPart1(300);` after the `primaryStage.show()` line to replicate my condition. The totals column should show 343 but shows 99 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. It turns out I need use bindings to accomplish what I was searching for.
The following is the improved code sample from @Sai which does what I need to. Relevant docs are [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;

public class test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Download>  downloads = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        downloads.add(new Download(23,56));
        downloads.add(new Download(56,43));
        downloads.add(new Download(97,3));
        downloads.add(new Download(67,23));

        TableView<Download> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Download, Integer> part1Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 1");
        part1Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part1Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Integer> part2Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 2");
        part2Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part2Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Integer> totalCol = new TableColumn<>("Total");
        totalCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            return Bindings.createObjectBinding(()-> { return (param.getValue().getPart1()+param.getValue().getPart2());} ,param.getValue().part1Property(),param.getValue().part2Property());
            });


        tableView.getColumns().addAll(part1Col,part2Col, totalCol);
        tableView.setItems(downloads);
        Scene sc = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
        downloads.get(1).setPart1(300);
    }

    class Download{
        SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part1 = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);
        SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part2= new SimpleObjectProperty<>(0);
        public Download(int p1, int p2){
            part1.set(p1);
            part2.set(p2);

        }

        public int getPart1() {
            return part1.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part1Property() {
            return part1;
        }

        public void setPart1(int part1) {
            this.part1.set(part1);
        }

        public int getPart2() {
            return part2.get();
        }

        public SimpleObjectProperty<Integer> part2Property() {
            return part2;
        }

        public void setPart2(int part2) {
            this.part2.set(part2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok considering your requirment, I think firstly you need to define your properties as IntegerProperty rather than wrapping Integer in ObjectProperty (as per javafx standards). This way, for addition you can directly use the number binding provided by IntegerProperty. Ofcourse with this change you need to define your TableColumn data type as Number.

If you are very keen to define the datatype of column as Integer only, then you can call the asObject() method in you cellValueFactory. Personally I dont prefer an extra layer of object creation using asObject() and casting to IntegerBinding :)

```
IntegerProperty part1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

TableColumn<Download, Integer> part1Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 1");
part1Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part1Property().asObject());

TableColumn<Download, Integer> totalCol = new TableColumn<>("Total");
    totalCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> ((IntegerBinding)param.getValue().part1Property().add(param.getValue().part2Property())).asObject());
```

Below is an updated code (a bit more clean) of the previous demo with the above changes, which will update the Part1 value of first row and the total column value updates automatically.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CustomCellValueFactoryDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Download> downloads = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        downloads.add(new Download(23, 56));
        downloads.add(new Download(56, 43));
        downloads.add(new Download(97, 3));
        downloads.add(new Download(67, 23));

        TableView<Download> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Download, Number> part1Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 1");
        part1Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part1Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Number> part2Col = new TableColumn<>("Part 2");
        part2Col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part2Property());

        TableColumn<Download, Number> totalCol = new TableColumn<>("Total");
        totalCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().part1Property().add(param.getValue().part2Property()));


        tableView.getColumns().addAll(part1Col, part2Col, totalCol);
        tableView.setItems(downloads);

        Scene sc = new Scene(tableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Updating the value dynamically.
        Download firstRow = downloads.get(0);
        Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), e -> firstRow.setPart1(firstRow.getPart1() + 1)));
        tl.setCycleCount(50);
        tl.play();
    }

    class Download {
        IntegerProperty part1 = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        IntegerProperty part2 = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Download(int p1, int p2) {
            part1.set(p1);
            part2.set(p2);

        }

        public int getPart1() {
            return part1.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty part1Property() {
            return part1;
        }

        public void setPart1(int part1) {
            this.part1.set(part1);
        }

        public int getPart2() {
            return part2.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty part2Property() {
            return part2;
        }

        public void setPart2(int part2) {
            this.part2.set(part2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't post several answers - instead edit one and add options (or decide which one is your favourite and only keep that one) BTW, don't know what you are refering to in _as by fx standards_